# Measure of a set, convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable real-valued functions which is Cauchy. Select a subsequence $(g_k)$ of $(f_n)$ such that the set $E_k=\{x\in X: |g_{k+1}-g_k(x)|\geq 2^{-k} \}$ is such that $\mu(E_k)<2^{-k}$. Let $F_k=\bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$ so that $\mu(F_k)<2^{-(k-1)}$.

I know that $\mu(E_k)<2^{-(k-1)}$ but i don't know how to prove that $\mu(F_k)<2^{-(k-1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mu(F_k)\leq\sum_{j=k}^\infty\mu(E_k)<\frac{2^{-k}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2^{-k+1}=2^{-(k-1)}$$

Comment: The first equal should be "$<$".

Comment: Of course. I have edited it now! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)